# Yii2 Почему сохраняется модель?

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2

Почему у меня выполняется $model->save() на продакшене, при этом далеко не все поля заполнены и нету значения по умолчанию.

На локалхосте модель не сохраняется, пишется что нету дефолтного значения. Это какие то настройки в Yii2? Ничего не понимаю. Код одинаков

Comment: Приведите пример кода

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322351/why-does-this-activerecordsave-successfully-save-the-model/37322879?

Comment: У вас там rule с required закомментирован ну и настройки mysql надо смотреть у вас на продакшене

Comment: какие именно настройки mysql?